# Find those id-s where no prohibitive conditions

Tags: sql, subquery, exists, dense-rank

I have some subseletions with "easier" conditions but this is out of my league.
So i have a table after joins...

```
A  B    C
1  x  2013.01
1  y  2013.02
1  z  2013.03
2  x  2013.02
2  x  2013.05
2  y  2013.06
2  z  2013.08
2  z  2013.09
3  y  2013.02
3  z  2013.03
3  x  2013.04
```

So I need those id-s where exists z, BUT no x exists before.

> So the result only 3 because z exists and x not exitst before.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Table1 t1 
     left join Table1 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A and t2.B = 'x'
where t1.B = 'z'
    and ( t2.C >= t1.C or t2.A is null );
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbf39b/3/0)